# TS error: Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Error | PromiseLike<Error | undefined> | undefined'.ts(2345)

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, mobx, mobx-persist

I am using [Mobx Persist Store](https://github.com/quarrant/mobx-persist-store) that saves MobX Store to Local Storage.

The docs doesn't have a TS version so I modified 2 lines (one in `readStore` & another in `writeStore` which you can compare with https://github.com/quarrant/mobx-persist-store#with-mobx-6) to solve TS errors but that caused another error:

```
import {
    persistence,
    useClear,
    useDisposers,
    isSynchronized,
    StorageAdapter,
} from 'mobx-persist-store'

import { FrameItStore } from '@/store/index'

function readStore(name: string) {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
        const data = localStorage.getItem(name) || '{}'
        resolve(JSON.parse(data))
    })
}

function writeStore(name: string, content: string) {
    return new Promise<Error | undefined>((resolve) => {
        localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(content))
        resolve(null)
    })
}

export default persistence({
    name: 'FrameItStore',
    properties: ['counter'],
    adapter: new StorageAdapter({
        read: readStore,
        write: writeStore,
    }),
    reactionOptions: {
        // optional
        delay: 2000,
    },
})(new FrameItStore())
```

I am getting an error on the `null` in `resolve(null)` inside of `writeStore`.

Here's the error:

> Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Error | PromiseLike<Error | undefined> | undefined'.ts(2345)

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it as I see no errors now. I had to remove `JSON.parse` from `readStore` as well as use `resolve(undefined)` instead of `resolve(null)` in `writeStore` like:

```
import {
    persistence,
    useClear,
    useDisposers,
    isSynchronized,
    StorageAdapter,
} from 'mobx-persist-store'

import { FrameItStore } from '@/store/index'

function readStore(name: string) {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
        const data = localStorage.getItem(name) || '{}'
        resolve(data)
    })
}

function writeStore(name: string, content: string) {
    return new Promise<Error | undefined>((resolve) => {
        localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(content))
        resolve(undefined)
    })
}

export const PersistState = persistence({
    name: 'FrameItStore',
    properties: ['counter'],
    adapter: new StorageAdapter({
        read: readStore,
        write: writeStore,
    }),
    reactionOptions: {
        // optional
        delay: 2000,
    },
})(new FrameItStore())
```

Answer (score 1):

`unknown` is not compatible with `string` or `undefined`. I believe that JSON.parse is returning `unknown`. So rather than just resolving `JSON.parse(data)` you have to determine its type. You can do this by using conditional checks. Once you are sure it's a `string` you can resolve it, otherwise resolve `undefined`.

```js
function readStore(name: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const data = localStorage.getItem(name) || '{}'
        const output = JSON.parse(data);
        if (typeof output === "string") resolve(output);
        resolve(undefined);
    })
}
```